# How do you reference an absolute URL in Next.js <Head>?

Tags: next.js, facebook-opengraph, absolute-path

I am trying to use `next/head` to dynamically set an `og:image`, which requires an absolute URL.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/og.jpg" />
```

How can I get `https://example.com` (the protocol and host)?

I tried using `window.location.origin`:

```
import Head from 'next/head';

const CustomHead = () => {
  const origin = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window?.location?.origin : '';

  return (
    <Head>
      <meta property="og:image" content={`${origin}/og.jpg`} />
    </Head>
  );
}
```

But this always uses the `''` fallback and renders `/og.jpg`, a relative URL, which is strange, because if I `console.log(origin);` I can see the absolute URL. What is happening here? Is it because `<Head>` is only being rendered once on the server?

Is there an environment variable that can be used to reference the absolute URL?